# Windows Service: EF + MySql without app.config

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, windows-services, entity-framework-6

At the moment I'm writing a windows service.

I'm already using EntityFramework with MSSQL database which is working perfectly. Now I have to use MySql parallely. But I can't manage to get it running ... I would like to avoid using the app.config and configure EntityFramework via the constructor of my class derived from DbContext.

I have a SqlContext class:

```
public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<ServiceauftragSource> ServiceauftragSource { get; set; }

    public SqlContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public SqlContext(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

In the constructor of my UnitOfWork I try to create my SqlContext:

```
    public SqlUnitOfWork()
    {
        const string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=myuser;pwd=mypw;database=mydb;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        this.Context = new SqlContext(conn);
    }
```

This didn't work. I get the following message when trying to access the database:

```
Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

Neither did:

```
    public SqlUnitOfWork()
    {
        this.SetConnectionString();
        this.Context = new SqlContext(connectionString);
    }

    private void SetConnectionString()
    {
        this.connectionString = "Data Source=" + debugDatabaseServer + ";Initial Catalog=" + debugDatabaseName 
                                        + ";User ID=" + debugDatabaseUsername + ";Password=" + debugDatabasePassword 
                                        + ";Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True;";            
    }
```

I'm not sure why but I think this is because I haven't told my context its provider (according to other threads on SO it has to be MySql.Data.MySqlClient). But where and how to?

References of the project:
[image: References in VS2010]

---

**Update**

I tried to use my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MySqlContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;
        port=3306;database=***;uid=***;password=***"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, 
          MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
    </entityFramework>
  </configuration>
```

When accessing the database I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I think this is because my service can't access the app.config after it's being installed. I ensured that app.config is MyService.exe.config after build ...

Comment: You specify the provider in the app/web config

Comment: I tried to. See updated question. Still not working :(.

Comment: Any solutions yet? I followed the advice from [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) but I always get the error "Unable to determine the DbProviderFactory type for connection of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config." My custom DbConfiguration is correctly called and I call SetDefaultConnectionFactory and SetProviderServices there, but it does not help.

Comment: No solution. I don't use MySQL with EF anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using MySQL with EF for quite some time pretty flawlessly, what yo need to do is add the following line above your DBContext

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof (MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

so in your case  the snippet would look like

```
 [DbConfigurationType(typeof (MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]   
 public class SqlContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<ServiceauftragSource> ServiceauftragSource { get; set; }

    public SqlContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public SqlContext(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

as for your connection string, i tend to store mine in the web config and then string format for whatever db,server or user i need to create a context for - hope that helps!

NB Im presuming you have your refs to MySQL.data and EF6 as well!